# How to use just one tree in a random forest with the R package randomForest?

Tags: r, random-forest

With the R package randomForest, I can get a forest for classification. With the function getTree(), I can get each tree of the forest. Now, my question is how to do classification for a new input data point x with just a specific tree, say the first tree of the forest. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You can extract the prediction for a single tree from the predictions for the whole forest if you include the `predict.all = T` argument. For example, if you made a forest from the iris data and want the predictions for tree 1:

```
model <- randomForest(iris[,-5], iris[,5], ntree=10)
predict(model, iris, predict.all=T)$individual[,1] # predictions for tree 1
```

The `getTree()` function just prints out the structure of the tree, but you would need to write your own function to use it for prediction directly.